# How to change background color of custom notification depending on day/night mode

Tags: android, android-layout

We are a small group working on a school assignment. We have created a custom notification, and it works fine. The only problem is i'm having a hard time figuring out how to make the custom notification change background color depending on if it's in day or night mode.

My code for creating the notification

```
Intent challengedIntent = new Intent(this, StartActivity.class); 
stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(challengedIntent);
PendingIntent challengedPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.app_channel))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.carfight_launcher)
            .setCustomContentView(views)
            .setCustomBigContentView(views)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setContentIntent(challengedPendingIntent)
            .setColorized(true)
            .setColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));

views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagesVeiw_wins,R.drawable.ic_medal_solid);
views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageVeiw_matches,R.drawable.ic_battle);


NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

How do i change it to react on day/night mode?

minSDKVersion is 16

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the ways to do this is to first determine if the phone is in night mode.
This can be done with the following code:

```
int nightModeFlags =
    getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode &
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
switch (nightModeFlags) {
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
         setupNightMode();
         break;

    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
         setupDayMode();
         break;

    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED:
         doStuff();
         break;
}
```

Then once you know if it is in night mode, simply create your RemoteView object accordingly. Which means you will have to have two layouts , one for normal mode, and another for night mode.
Something like this:

```
RemoteView remoteView;

//Switch case here

setupNightMode(){
remoteView = new RemoteView() //inflate night mode layout
}


setupDayMode()
{
remoteView = new RemoteView() //inflate day mode layout
}
```

Finally:
Use the remoteView object while building the notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = ...
```

Comment: While this works, it's making assumptions about what background colour the OS uses, which is OS-dependent. For example, AOSP Android 9 uses white notification background in dark theme, whereas AOSP Android 10 uses dark notification background in dark theme. To make matters more complicated, Samsung also uses dark notification background on Android 9 in dark theme.

Comment: @Sam Thank you for the comment. Yes, the answer might be making assumption about the color the OS uses but you also seem to assume developers lack common sense on what to use for dark mode and what not. Lol.